# How to access all channels of OpenCV image

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have an OpenCV image created like this:

```
cv::Mat img(XN_VGA_Y_RES, XN_VGA_X_RES, CV_64FC3, cv::Scalar(0));
```

How can I access all its pixels?

I tried:

```
for (int x=0; x < XN_VGA_X_RES; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < XN_VGA_Y_RES; y++) {
        img.at<double>(y,x) = 1;
    }
}
```

However, when I do it this way only 1/3 of the image is white. I'm guessing this is because there are 3 channels in my image, but how can I access them all? I tried various stuff like `img.at<double[3]>(y,x)` or `img.at<cv::Vec3f>(y,x)`, but they do not seem to work.

Comment: you can also use `img = 1` with the same result as the for loops

Comment: @vasile: right, the above code is just an example, I'm using different values than `1` in the real one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
img.at<cv::Vec3d>(y, x)[0] = 1;
img.at<cv::Vec3d>(y, x)[1] = 1;
img.at<cv::Vec3d>(y, x)[2] = 1;
```